# Olympic statistics question about points

Tags: problem-solving, word-problem

Score of **180cm** in highjump gives **627** points and **190cm** gives **714** points. **40m** discus throw gives **665** points and **45m** throw **767** points. James's jump result is **188cm**, and discus throw **41m**. if the result of the jump deteriorate by **5cm**, how much the discus throw result has to get better for the total score to stay the same.

I tried to solve this with no luck, because i have no idea how to even start. It would be great to get some directions on how to solve this.

Comment: They must be assuming a linear relationship between the result and number of points. So: try and figure out how many point you gain when you jump 1 cm higher, or throw 1 m further, and go from there.

Comment: Since they give you only two data points in each event, I imagine that they are first asking you to express the points received in each event as a linear function of the result - height jumped or distance thrown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding to what Bram28 and Malcolm said the linear relationships for jumps and throws are

$$jump = 8.7(j-180)+627$$
$$throw = 20.4(t-40)+665$$

This gives James's initial score of 1382. I will leave the rest to you.